# Resuming music in android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, onresume

Music does not resume after pressing home button and then pressing the app from recent list. Please make necessary changes in the code given.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mySound.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mySound != null)
            mySound.start();
    }

    MediaPlayer mySound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.sleep);
        mySound.start();
        mySound.setLooping(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: Please reformulate your question and provide more info about it

Comment: code in the answer

Comment: The `start()` method in `onResume()` won't work since you have already called `release()` in `onPause()`. (According to [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `Activity`'s `onPause()` method, just change it to.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mySound != null)
        mySound.pause();
}
```

Only ever call release() on a `MediaPlayer` when you no longer need it. From the Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release())

> **void release()**
>
> Releases resources associated with this MediaPlayer object. It is
> considered good practice to call this method when you're done using
> the MediaPlayer.

So instead use `pause()`

> **void pause()**
>
> Pauses playback. Call start() to resume.

Have a look at the state diagram of a `MediaPlayer`
[image: MediaPlayer State Diagram]

What the diagram represents are valid states where it is *OK* to use the `MediaPlayer` object.

Comment: requirements=The music should pause when i press home button and continue from where it was paused when i open the app from recent apps list.

Comment: @Anvaypancholiya Works for me. What do you mean when you say "not working still"?

Comment: means the music does not resume from where ut wa closed

Comment: @Anvaypancholiya works for me. I get the playback onResume and playback resumes from the time I left it at. Read through the answer once more and recheck your code. If that doesn't help then post a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that carries your problem.